# Web RTC Local audio issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am trying to implement a webrtc-based video chat room and I encountered the following problem. 
 When the call starts and my local stream goes, I listen to my audio on my device before the other device receives it. The devices are far enough apart so that the echo does not affect them. I don't know if that happens because I did something wrong or it is always like that.
I appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: What is the question? To listen to the local audio?

Comment: The question would be how to eliminate the local audio feedback I am getting. I don't know if that happens because I did something wrong or it's always like that. Thanks.

Comment: Your RTC view uses the localStream. Maybe you're putting it into a video tag that isn't muted. In that case add "mute" to the video elem

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this occurs only when the connection is established, so I don't think the problem has to do with that.

Comment: You didn't provide the code where you actually use the stream. It is definitely somewhere that you put the stream where sound comes out. Maybe you switched the streams in some way.

Comment: Is the feedback like realtime or does it have a little delay on it? Maybe the other peer resends the stream he got instead of sending the local one.

Comment: Yes, it has a little delay.